# Add a supplemental attribute tables per project

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have a layer that has base attributes. I'd like to create supplemental attributes that particular to each project that base layer is used in, but doesn't affect the core data (or isn't available in other projects).

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that your base layer is a vector layer, then you can use the following way:

- open the layers properties
- goto the auxiliary storage tab
- select "create" at the bottom of the window

[image]

- select a primary key to link the auxiliary data to your layer
- add as many fields you need wtith the desired type

[image]

the data will be only available within your project and is linked to the layer and available over the attribute table...